# How can do a confusion matrix with RandomForest Classifier?

Tags: python, random-forest, confusion-matrix

I used the following code, which works- however I want to applicate it specifically on RandomForest?

````
ax.matshow(conf_matrix, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=0.3)
for i in range(conf_matrix.shape[0]):
    for j in range(conf_matrix.shape[1]):
        ax.text(x=j, y=i,s=conf_matrix[i, j], va='center', ha='center', size='xx-large')
 
plt.xlabel('Predictions', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Actuals', fontsize=18)
plt.title('Confusion Matrix', fontsize=18)
plt.show() ```

Thank you for your help!
````

Comment: So what is the question? The matrix shows ground truth Vs classifier results. The classifier type doesn't matter

Comment: The problem is I put the confusion matrix code at the end of my training model code. Now, I would like to do a confusion matrix for the best performing and worst performing model. Since I have put the code at the end, I have one confusion matrix but dont know to which model it relates....